# Restrict author to create subcategory in a selected category

Tags: categories, author

I am looking for a way to restrict AuthorA.
I want to restrict him to post only in CatA and allow him to create subcategory in catA.
So he will be able to post in CatA and in the subcategories he create by his own.

I found this but doesn't restrict him to post a selected parent category :

```
class SW_Category_Restriction{
    private $user_cats = NULL;

    public function __construct(){
        //Save author ID for category
        add_action( 'create_category', array( &$this, 'save_category_author' ) );
        //Set manage_categories cap for 'Author'
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( &$this, 'add_author_cap_categories' ) );
        //Remove manage_categories  capfor 'Author'
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'remove_author_cap_categories' ) );
        //Filter categorys in new-post, edit-post, edit-categories
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', array( &$this, 'filter_post_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', array( &$this, 'filter_post_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-edit-tags.php', array( &$this, 'filter_post_page' ) );
        //just show own posts
        global $pagenow;
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' )
            add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'filter_edit_page' ) );
    }

    public function save_category_author( $term_id ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'author', $user_id );
    }

    public function get_user_cats( $user_id ) {
        $args = [
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => 'author',
                    'value' => $user_id,
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );
        $ids = '-1,';
        foreach ($terms as $term ) {
            $ids .= $term->term_id . ',';
        }
        $ids = substr($ids, 0, -1);
        $this->user_cats = $ids;
    }

    public function add_author_cap_categories() {
        $role = get_role( 'author' );
        $role->add_cap( 'manage_categories' );
    }

    public function remove_author_cap_categories() {
        $role = get_role( 'author' );
        $role->remove_cap( 'manage_categories' );
    }

    public function exclusions( $exclusions ){
        $exclusions .= " AND ( t.term_id IN ( $this->user_cats ) OR tt.taxonomy NOT IN ( 'category' ) )";
        return $exclusions;
    }

    public function filter_post_page() {
        //check post-type 
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if ( $screen->post_type != 'post' )
            return;

        //just Author and lower
        if ( current_user_can('delete_others_posts') )
            return;

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $this->get_user_cats( $user_id );

        if ( empty( $this->user_cats ) )
            return;

        add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', array( &$this, 'exclusions' ) );
    }

    public function filter_edit_page( $query ) {
        if ( current_user_can('delete_others_posts') )
            return;     
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );

        return $query;
    }

}

new SW_Category_Restriction();
```

Comment: have you looked at plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-author-posting/ or does it have to be your own code?

Comment: I've already looked at the plugin but I have to manually slect a category and sub cat. But I want him to be able to add the sub cat

Comment: you can add a check for the parent category inside save_category_author